# Returning default list if the list is empty using java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, option-type

Is there any way so that the below can be performed as one set of stream operations, instead of explicitly checking *if recommendedProducts is empty then return default list else return the filtered list*?

```
public List<Product> getRecommendedProducts() {
    List<Product> recommendedProducts 
        = this.newProducts
              .stream()
              .filter(isAvailable)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (recommendedProducts.isEmpty()) {
        return DEFAULT_PRODUCTS;
    }

    return recommededProducts;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your existing code?

Comment: @AndyTurner Agree. The code is good as it is. The only improvement I would do is using *ternary operator* instead of *if-else* statement. It is still a matter of taste though.

Comment: @ETO  There is nothing wrong, but I was trying/hoping to find out if there is a way to do it just by using Stream APIs with out explicit condition checks. Thanks for the reply - I like the ternary operator suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this:

```
List<Product> recommendedProducts 
        = this.newProducts
              .stream()
              .filter(isAvailable)
              .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> list.isEmpty() ? DEFAULT_PRODUCTS : list));
```

Answer (score 5):

While you could achieve your goal using `Optional`, I would still opt for plain old ternary operator.

In this particular case it makes much more sense and improves readability:

```
return recommendedProducts.isEmpty() ? DEFAULT_PRODUCTS : recommendedProducts;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes by using `Optional`

```
return Optional.of(this.newProducts.stream()
                                   .filter(isAvailable)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .filter(l->!l.isEmpty())
                    .orElse(DEFAULT_PRODUCTS);
```